# select multiple options

Tags: php, html

banging my head against the wall for something seemingly dead simple.

Here it is:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="action.php">
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="Newspaper"> <span >Newspaper</span></div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="PC"> <span >PC</span></div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="Home"> <span >Home</span></div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="Dont_know"> <span >dnunno</span></div>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I select more then one option. I see in my `print_r($_POST);` statement only the last selected option in stead of all selected options. 
How should I deal with this?

update:
I checked the rest of my code and i saw that this is done by some JavaScript.

```
else if (aform.validatorArr[i][4] == "checkbox") {
    var fvs = "";
    eval("var chkbArray=aform." + aform.validatorArr[i][1] + ";");
    if (aform.validatorArr[i][2] == "cb_true") {
        for (k = 0; k < chkbArray.length; k++) {
            if (chkbArray[k].checked) {
                fvs += chkbArray[k].value;
                console.log(fvs);
            }
        }
        if (fvs == false) {
            s += aform.validatorArr[i][3] + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

That's why the [] is not added in my html. But how could I modify this code so that it will take all options?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put [] after the name:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="test[]" value="Newspaper">
```

See [PHP FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) for more details.

Comment: Then you can foreach($_POST["test"] as $test) { ... }

Comment: @sanders - the code you posted is an excerpt, and it's really hard to understand without seeing the rest of what's happening. From what I can gather, the fvs variable is a concatenation of all values from the selected checkboxes, but I can't see where that's going.